# Как подключить X11 к Qt проекту на MacOS High Sierra

Tags: c++, qt, mac, x11

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать вот такой проект

```
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>
#include <dlib/dnn.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/clustering.h>
#include <dlib/string.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace dlib;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    frontal_face_detector detector = get_frontal_face_detector();
    matrix <rgb_pixel> image;
    load_image(image, "/Users/ivanlebedev/Desktop/Projects/ManSearch/cars/2.jpg");
    image_window win(image);
}
```

Но мне выдает такую ошибку

```
/usr/local/Cellar/dlib/19.15/include/dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:12: ошибка: "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
#error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
 ^
```

Как я могу подключить x11 к своему проекту

Comment: libx11-dev установлен?

Comment: Ошибка: `Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system`, говорит о том что вам необходимо убедиться в том что пакет `libx11-dev` установлен в вашей системе.

Comment: Попробуйте установить x11 через brew